# Why can't I find the icon files of the old OSX online (there are only Imitative ones)?

Tags: macos

Is it because it is an infringement to extract the system icons and upload them to the network? Or simply because we are lazy and no one to extract?

Comment: The icons are certainly copyrighted and my understanding is that anyone distributing it without the owner's (that is, Apple's) expressed consent would be infringing copyright.

Comment: If you have a machine running the "old" OS (whichever that is), then you can get them. Not a good idea to post them though.

Comment: What icon files are you talking about exactly ?  I can help if it is  keyboard flags.

Comment: Define what "old OSX" means.  You can download the OS yourself back to Yosemite and extract whatever you want.  Can't PUBLISH it, it's not your IP, but getting them is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Icons used in macOS are copyrighted by Apple and can‘t be published online.

PS: I‘m sure there are sites out there which host them, but they might not show up easily in search engines.